# discord.py how to temporarily block execution to get a new instruction from the user

Tags: discord.py

Hi I'm creating an initial tutorial for new members of my discord server and I'm stuck on one point:
I would like it during the execution of the tutorial to freeze momentarily to let the user choose options but I don't know how to do it, I think it may be from the asyncio library but I don't know.
I send the complete code:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == "start":
        #ruoli
        accademico_in_preparazione = get(guild.roles, id=int("746178678274261043"))
        mappercell = get(guild.roles, id=int("746187955315540059"))
        mapperpc = get(guild.roles, id=int("746187952987701250"))
        accademico = get(guild.roles, id=int("690964416644251750"))
        #canali
        regolamento = client.get_channel(727304286215733249)
        annunci = client.get_channel(675101744115744789)
        programmazione = client.get_channel(724936407835213914)
        generaleacc = client.get_channel(697872690505187328)
        corsibase = client.get_channel(675103006953570324)
        guida = client.get_channel(724680601482952714)
        regolamentolmii = client.get_channel(646026232420368395)
        costituzione = client.get_channel(643547822284865556)
        generale = client.get_channel(640563710104043530)
        #rendere utilizzabile il comando su un canale specifico
        channel = client.get_channel(746145103403286618)
        if ctx.channel.id == channel.id:
            await ctx.channel.set_permissions(accademico_in_preparazione, read_messages=True, send_messages=False)
            await message.channel.send("Salve nuovo accademico benvenuto nell'accademia del LMII!")
            await asyncio.sleep(5)
            await message.channel.send("Prima di lasciarti la libertà ti spiego alcune cose importanti")
            await asyncio.sleep(5)
            await message.channel.send("Essendo un accademico sei limitato rispetto ad altri membri, il tuo compito è quello di completare i corsi dedicati per diventare ufficialmente un membro del LMII!")
            await asyncio.sleep(7.5)
            await message.channel.send("Perchè non posso imparare essendo direttamente membro?")
            await asyncio.sleep(5)
            await message.channel.send("Ci teniamo che i nostri membri ufficiali siano già dei bravi mapper che abbiano delle basi solite, ti consiglio vivamente di guardare questi seguenti canali:")
            await asyncio.sleep(7.5)
            await message.channel.send(f"{regolamento.mention} : Il regolamento della nostra accademia!")
            await asyncio.sleep(2)
            await message.channel.send(f"{annunci.menttion} : gli annunci dell'accademia , potresti ricevere (in caso hai i messaggi privati aperti) dei messaggi privati dal bot che sono degli annunci importanti del server")
            await asyncio.sleep(8)
            await message.channel.send(f"{programmazione.mention} : qui c'è il programma dell'accademia , dacci un occchiata!")
            await asyncio.sleep(5)
            await message.channel.send(f"{generaleacc.mention} : questo è il canale dove si può parlare di tutto riguardante l'accademia sfruttalo per ogni evenienza")
            await asyncio.sleep(6)
            await message.channel.send(f"{corsibase.mention} : qui ci sono le informazioni sui corsi che interessano a te! ")
            await asyncio.sleep(5)
            await message.channel.send(f"{guida.mention} : qui per altre informazioni dettagliate sull'accademia!")
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            await message.channel.send(f"\n")
            await asyncio.sleep(5)
            await message.channel.send(f"Essendo accademico hai accessi limitati ma puoi accedere tranquillamente alla zona mapping nel LMII e ai canali principali della zona pubblica fra cui {generale.mention} dove puoi parlare di tutto e fare buone conoscenze!")
            await asyncio.sleep(10)
            await message.channel.send(f"Attenzione ci sono da rispettare anche il {regolamentolmii.mention} e la {costituzione.mention} che sono molto importanti!")
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            await message.channel.send(f"\n")
            await asyncio.sleep(6)
            await message.channel.send(f"Ora dovrai rispondere semplicemente ad una domanda per poi poter finalmente accedere a tutti i canali!")
            await asyncio.sleep(10)
            await message.channel.send(f"Sei un mapper da **telefono** o da **PC**?")
            await asyncio.sleep(5)
            await ctx.channel.set_permissions(message.author, send_messages=True)
            ????
            await ctx.channel.set_permissions(message.author, overwrite=None)
            if message.content == "PC":
                await message.channel.send("Quindi sei un mapper da pc!")
                await message.author.add_roles(mapperpc)
                await message.channel.send("Ora tutti sapranno che sei un mapper da PC , in caso cambi idea chiedi a qualche amministratore di cambiare il ruolo in modo manuale!")
                await asyncio.sleep(6)
                await message.channel.send("Ora sei pronto! Se vuoi sapere di più sul bot digita **lmiihelp**\n\nBot programmato da : Peppewarrior Italy")
                await asyncio.sleep(7)
                await message.author.remove_roles(accademico_in_preparazione)
                await message.authro.add_roles(accademico)
                await asyncio.sleep(5)
                await message.channel.purge(limit=100)
                await ctx.channel.set_permissions(accademico_in_preparazione, read_messages=True)
            elif message.content == "telefono":
                await message.channel.send("Quindi sei un mapper da telefono!")
                await message.author.add_roles(mappercell)
                await message.channel.send("Ora tutti sapranno che sei un mapper da telefono , in caso cambi idea chiedi a qualche amministratore di cambiare il ruolo in modo manuale!")
                await asyncio.sleep(6)
                await message.channel.send("Ora sei pronto! Se vuoi sapere di più sul bot digita **lmiihelp**\n\nBot programmato da : Peppewarrior Italy")
                await asyncio.sleep(7)
                await message.author.remove_roles(accademico_in_preparazione)
                await message.authro.add_roles(accademico)
                await asyncio.sleep(5)
                await message.channel.purge(limit=100)
                await ctx.channel.set_permissions(accademico_in_preparazione, read_messages=True)
    await client.process_commands(message)
```

P.S if possible i can know how to make some messages immune from `channel.purge`?

Comment: In general to get user input we use `bot.wait_for('message')` that returns a Message object. `asyncio.sleep(x)` can be used to wait for x seconds.

Comment: gives me this error, how could I make it wait for an answer without giving me errors? 
[code and error](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/640563710104043530/746294797471580160/unknown.png)

Comment: your error seems to be from using `.lower()` directly on a `Message` object. Instead use , `message.content.lower()`

Comment: `It makes me the same mistake, I'm not understanding much about using `client.wait_for` [code](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/746145103403286618/746405689768804392/unknown.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use the [`client.wait_for()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=wait_for#discord.Client.wait_for) function to get input from the user throughout the execution, just add this code to the place where you want to get user input:

```
await ctx.send("Choose an option:\n1. Option 1 details here\n2. Option 2 details here\n3. Option 3 details here")
option = await client.wait_for('message', check=lambda message: message.author == ctx.author and message.content != "")
option = option.content;

if (option == "1"):
    # Do something if user chooses 1
elif (option == "2"):
    # Do something if user chooses 2
elif (option == "3"):
    # Do something if user chooses 3
```

Comment: Your comment helped me but I would like when the user writes the option the desired option starts directly and not put a time limit.
[Code](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/661206705295589397/746472155553857616/unknown.png)

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. Remove `await asyncio.sleep(5)` if you want it to start immediately.

Comment: If I remove asyncio.sleep it doesn't give me time to write the answer which ends the execution

Comment: Unfortunately it gives me more time but it is little, I would like the user to have an indefinite time to write the option. [code](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/746145103403286618/746511531881005137/unknown.png)

Comment: ah yes I did not put ctx.author because apart from giving me an error I don't need it in this case

Comment: I've updated the `check` in the answer, see if that works.

Comment: Ok now go! Thanks for everything.

If you like, could you help me here too? [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63529793/discord-py-how-to-make-a-message-undeletable-from-channel-purge/63530403#63530403)

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [`Client.wait_for`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for), which is used to wait for a user reply. There is a very simple example of how you can implement this in the discord.py docs.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('$greet'):
        channel = message.channel
        await channel.send('Say hello!')

        def check(m):
            return m.content == 'hello' and m.channel == channel

        msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
        await channel.send('Hello {.author}!'.format(msg))
```

Comment: I need him to give different answers, the example did not help me