# discord.py: how to make a message undeletable from channel.purge

Tags: discord.py

My question is very simple:
I am scheduling an event that will then delete all messages but I would like the first message never to be deleted from `channel.purge`.
Since users could write 2/3 more messages they could remain if I wanted to be precise when I use `channel.purge` and I know of a function of mee6 that did not delete 2 week old messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`discord.TextChannel.purge`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=purge#discord.TextChannel.purge) function allows you filter out what messages are deleted using the `check` parameter. This means you can create your own check that will check the message to meet your requirements:

```
def check(m):
    messageID = 1234567890 # Replace this with the message you want to keep
    return m.id != messageID # Bot will ignore the message if it finds the specified Message ID

await channel.purge(check=check)
```

Comment: I can declare that it must not delete a specific message right?
if so how can I do? This is new to me.

Comment: I've edited the answer with an example which should hopefully work, let me know.